# Using locally stored images in hero card

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to use images located in my project directory as the images in my hero cards.  This doesn't seem to work.  Is it only possible to add images to hero cards from a URL? Thanks

Updated Solution:

```
var image64 = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(<image path>).toString("base64");
var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
             .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+image64)]);
```

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Comment: I'm using Node SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending the images as URLs is not the only way. You can also send them encoded in base64:

```
        byte[] imagedata = {image}
        var image64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imagedata);

        reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
        {
            ContentUrl = image64,
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know if HeroCards accept images in base64 format? Or do they have to be sent as separate attachments like how you're doing it?

Comment: @Ezequiel Is this answer in C# or Node?

Comment: @Ezequiel my question is specific to HeroCards. If this doesn't apply to HeroCards, please let me know.

Comment: @Justin, I'm pretty sure it will apply to hero cards too. Have you tried it? Set the CardImage url to be the Base 64 encoded image

Comment: @Ezequiel I was able to get it working through a slightly different approach to make it work in node.js, but your idea was correct